# Wat is the Arduino IDE platform define?

Tags: arduino, c-preprocessor

Linux, windows and macOS all have ways to determine that you are compiling this piece on code a platform. (`__linux__`, `__WIN32__`, `__APPLE__`, etc…) All compilers also have ways of determining the specific compiler (`__GNUC__`, `__clang__`, etc…).

What define exists to determine that you are compiling inside the arduino framework and as such `Arduino.h` is available.

I would like something more general than the options: `__AVR_ATmega328P__`, `ARDUINO_AVR_UNO`,`ESP8266`,`__SAMD51__`, etc… as these all require a big list to include.

Comment: `#ifdef ARDUINO`. see compiler command line in platform.txt for -D defines

Answer (score 1):

Check if your version of Arduino.h still starts with

```
 #ifndef Arduino_h
 #define Arduino_h
```

The IDE adds `#include <Arduino.h>` to the start of the combined .ino files, so

```
 #ifdef Arduino_h
```

will tell that all the Arduino stuff is available.

Comment: `#ifdef ARDUINO`. see compiler command line in platform.txt for -D defines